# Fallback to local if dependency not found in npm public registry

Tags: node.js, npm

i am installing a npm package which has multiple dependencies.
This package was supposed to be run in internal network.

But i need to install the same package in a public network system.

Out of the multiple dependencies, couple of them are available only in the private internal npm registry , others can be fetched from the registry.npmjs.org.

I can download those dependencies and install it locally on a publicly available system but cannot reach the private network from this system.

Is this possible for npm to fallback locally in case the dependency is not available in registry.npmjs.org ? I dont want to change the package.json

Best Regards,
Saurav

B